# Swift can closures really modify constants?

Tags: swift, closures, constants

In the subsection *Capturing Values* of the section *Closures*, Apple's book *The Swift Programming Language* says

> The closure can then refer to and modify the values of those constants and variables from within its body, even if the original scope that defined the constants and variables no longer exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be written as "refer to constants and refer to and modify variables"  Try the following in a playground:

```
let x = 1

println(x)

{ x = x + 1 }()

println(x)
```